Species Identification - Blue multi-segment arthropod
This bug has a blue body, more than 8 legs, an orange head, and on its behind it has two stripes that are sometimes found on centipedes. Sorta hard to remember size, but I estimate about half the size of my finger which is about 2.5 in
I found it in a dried out creek on a rock, and I am located around Possum Kingdom in SouthEast Texas, USA


This appears to be a larva of some species of notched-mouth ground beetle (Dicaelus spp.).

 Source: bugguide.net;  copyright 2008 Cotinis 
Notable characteristics:

blue coloration + orange head
large cerci
relatively large size + >10 body segments
location (TX fits in Canada-to-Mexico range)

See the following buggguide.net posts (1, 2, 3) for images.

#2 looks especially like the OP's specimen (and is from TX).

